# Object type logged differently in REPL than in execution

Tags: node.js

I ran across a puzzling bug the other day. I have a simple program like this:

```
// file.coffee
C = require('./C')
console.log typeof C
```

---

```
// C.coffee
module.exports = ->
    val: true
```

When I import the code in the node REPL, I see this:

```
a = require('./file.js')
// 'function'
```

But when I run is

```
// node ./file.js
// 'object'
```

Why is the type of the object being logged differently?

More importantly, since `C` is exported as a function, why is its type logged as 'object'?

Comment: I am not familiar with coffee script. I just test it with plain javascript in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/richzw/05cb029ed7a81b019f9f), both REPL and node file.js shown `function`..

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: The node version is `v5.3.0`

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work

Comment: Are you shure that you're not overriding some variables? I have object in both repl and explicitly invoking. (v5.6.0)

Comment: Yes im sure. I am on Windows though, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @dopatraman, what version of node do you use?

Comment: After convert your  coffee code to js code through `http://js2.coffee/`, both REPL and `node file.js` output `function`, and I test it under windows.

Comment: So when I run the code mentioned above, through _coffee-script at v1.10.0_ command-line and then load a _Node REPL at v5.3.0_, I get to following output:  
  
`$ node> a = require('./file.js')  
//function  
//{}  
> a  
//{}  
  
$ node ./file.js  
//function`